# Doctrine connection in Twig extension - Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig

According to what I've read online, it should be possible to create Doctrine connection inside Twig extensions file. I'd like to create an extension with filter that would recieve id of category and then return  position of that category in the categery tree as it was established in database.

Twig extension file:

```
(Symfony/src/MyProject/AdminBundle/Twig/MyExtension.php)

<?php

namespace MyProject\AdminBundle\Twig;

class ToolboxExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct($em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('path', array($this, 'categoryPath'))
        );
    }

    public function categoryPath($category_id) {
        $repository = $this->$em->getRepository('MyProjectAdminBundle:Category');
        $category = $repository->findOneById($category_id);
        $path = $repository->getPath($category);
        return implode(">", $path);
        return $category;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'toolbox_extension';
    }

}
```

Services configuration file:

```
(Symfony/src/MyProject/AdminBundle/Resources/config/services.yml)

services:
    myproject.twig.toolbox_extension:
        class: MyProject\AdminBundle\Twig\MyExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
        arguments:
            em: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

But whenever I use this filter categoryPath, Twig crashes. So the template is loaded only until the first usage of this extension.

Comment: Can you add some more information - *it crashes* really isnt that helpful .. what exactly happens ? what errors are in the logs (symfony/php/web server) ? what is displayed on the screen ?

Comment: I have not seen named arguments in service definitions before.  Too lazy to look up if they are legal.  Be kind of nice if they were.  In any event, try replacing em: with a -.  Also, $this->$em should be $this->em.  Finally, consider injecting the repository instead of the entity manager.  Eliminates having to know the category class name.

Comment: ManseUK: It doesn't return any specific error or warning, HTML response is successfully sent to the browser. But the source of response contains only that segment of template, which is there before  a filter call.

Comment: Cerad: Solved, thanks.

Comment: If you have solved the problem please post the solution as answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `$this->em->` with `$this->$em->`.

Comment: Also try to add EntityManager on your constructor not only the variable

Answer (score 1):

For me, solution below work perfect. I found post on [google groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/Symfony2/RVZGBJ4UHQ4/eJ4weM_78x4J) which resolve my problem with doctrine in Twig extensions.

In my AppBundle\Resources\services.yml:

```
app.twig.get_province.extension:
            class: AppBundle\Twig\GetProvinceExtension
            tags:
              - { name: twig.extension }
            arguments: [ '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager' ]
```

In AppBundle\Twig\GetProvinceExtention.php:

```
class GetProvinceExtension extends \Twig_Extension {

    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $em;

    /**
     * GetProvinceExtension constructor.
     * @param EntityManager $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function getFilters() {
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('province', [$this, 'provinceFilter']),
        ];
    }

    public function provinceFilter($code) {
        $province = $this->em->getRepository("AppBundle:Province")
            ->findOneBy([ "code" => $code ]);

        return $province->getName();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
$this->em->
```

with `$this->$em->` 
and replacing

```
$this->em = $em;
```

with

```
$this->em = $em['em'];
```

and
arguments:

```
em: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

with
arguments: `[em: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
{% set Products = repository('Entity\\Products').findAll() %}
```

inside your twig

Then you can do a foreach by using

```
{% Product in Products %}
     <p>{{ Product.name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```